# Test addListener with anonymous function inside - Angular Jasmine (Isolated Test)

Tags: angular, testing, mocking, jasmine, eventemitter

Someone here recently helped me with a function test, but I can't access a part of that function because it's an anonymous function inside an addListener.I read the documentation but I can't find anything about this. Is it possible to access these areas?

**This is my component code**

```
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

@Component({
  selector: "app-mug",
  templateUrl: "./mug.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./mug.component.scss"],
})
export class MugComponent implements OnInit
{
  @Output() nav: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  public mug: Mug= new Mug();

  constructor(
    public constants: Constants,
    public mugService: mugService,
    public basicService: BasicService,
    public toolsService: ToolsService,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
  ) 
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.basicService.siteChange.subscribe((value) => {
      this.mugService.filterC.id = value;
      this.mugService.getRelatedMugs(); 
    });
  }

  public openModal(contentType: string): void {
    this.toolsService.eventEmitter.removeAllListeners();
    this.toolsService.eventEmitter.addListener("close-modal", () =>
      this.toolsService.eventEmitter.removeAllListeners()
    );
    this.toolsService.eventEmitter.addListener(
      "contentEvent",
      (content) => {
        this.setContent(contentType, content);
      }
    );
    const data = {
      component: ModalSearchComponent,
      input: inputList,
      ModalTitle: "Mug finder",
    };
    const modalC = this.modalService.open(ModalContainerComponent, {
      size: "lg",
      backdrop: "static",
    });
    modalC.componentInstance.showComponent(data);
  }
}
```

**This is my Spec.ts code**

```
let modalService = jasmine.createSpyObj("modalService", ["open"]);
modalService.open.and.returnValue({
  componenntInstance: {
     showComponent: () => null,
  }
});
let toolsService = jasmine.createSpyObj("toolsService", ["toRoute"], {
    eventEmitter: {
      addListener: () => null,
      removeAllListeners: () => null,
    }
  });
....
component = new MugComponent(
      constants,
      mugService,
      basicService,
      toolsService,
      modalService,
    );
```

**This is my code coverage**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be, try this:

```
// !! this will get the most recent call for `addListener` and get a handle on the arguments
// !! the first element in the array is the stringArgument ("close-modal", "contentEvent") and the 2nd element is the function for the call.
const [stringArgument, function] = toolsService.addListener.calls.mostRecent().args;
```

The above will give you the last time (mostRecent()) `addListener` was called but if you want to have a handle of all of the calls, `calls` should have all of the calls I think.